# The skeleton of Eulerian polyhedra

Tags: general-topology, polyhedra, planar-graphs

There is (at least) two kind of validity domain of Euler's $v−e+f=2$ polyhedron formula. One is the "Eulerian" polyhedra, i.e. simply connected polyhedra with simply connected faces (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Polyhedron&oldid=662853671#Euler_characteristic)). The other is the connected planar graphs. We know, that not every connected planar graph is a skeleton of some polyhedron, only the 3-connected ones, so the second domain seems broader.

On the other hand, according [Steinitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem), every 3-connected planar graph is the skeleton of some *convex* polyhedron. And since every convex polyhedron is Eulerian, the set of polyhedra having 3-connected planar skeleton is a subset of the set of all Eulerian polyhedra. My question is, that is this a proper subset (since the simply connectedness of faces imply the connectedness of the skeleton, this would mean, that there are Eulerian polyhedra with non-planar skeleton ), or every Eulerian polyhedron is combinatorially equivalent to a convex polyhedron? (I call two polyhedra combinatorially equivalent if they have the same skeleton)

So, my real question is:

> Can the skeleton of an Eulerian polyhedron be non-planar?

Or, its reverse:

> Is it true that every Eulerian polyhedron is combinatorially equivalent to a convex polyhedron?

---

**Edit**:

I think, that "simply connected polyhedra with simply connected faces" is not sufficient for having Euler-Characteristic 2, because there are simply connected polyhedra with simply connected faces that aren't homeomorphic with $S^2$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286027/what-does-an-euler-characteristic-of-a-topological-space-greater-than-2-topologi)). It seems, that we should require additionally, that the polyhedra is topologically a manifold (or perhaps equivalently (?), that the polyhedron, and also its interior is connected). I think, that if we define "Eulerian polyhedron" so, then, according the comment of @BalarkaSen, we can state, that every Eulerian polyhedron is combinatorially equivalent to a convex polyhedron.

Comment: No nonplanar graph can appear as skeleton of an Euler polyhedra, since otherwise you'd be able to embed it inside a sphere (every closed simply connected polyhedra with simply connected faces is homeomorphic to $S^2$), contradicting nonplanarity.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Could you please provide a proof, or a reference for this statement: "every closed simply connected polyhedron with simply connected faces is homeomorphic to $S^2$?

Answer (score 0):

A simply connected polyhedron with simply connected faces is just an Eulerian polyhedron, i.e. of Euler characteristic 2 and an example of a topological S^2. Every such polyhedron can be made convex.

It is conventional to require that such a polyhedron be finite and 3-connected, and therefore every 3-connected planar graph corresponds to an Eulerian/convex polyhedron and vice versa.

The criteria can be relaxed, allowing other constructions as polyhedra. Allowing 2-connected graphs introduces some new examples such as the dihedra, although these are degenerate and have no finite convex form. Varying the Euler characteristic from 2 means that there is no equivalent planar graph and hence no convex form.