# Polyhedron with Euler characteristic equal to $3$

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Basically as the title says. I'm not able to find a polyhedron with Euler characteristic equal to $3$.

Comment: Hint: Consider two tetrahedra with a common vertex.

Comment: Another connected question/answer that I have easily found with a Google search using "Polyhedra Euler characteristic" and lookink at "images" : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286069

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. My problem was that I did not know that these kind of shapes are even counted as polyhedra. I guess I have to read the formal definition.